# error handling in stol() function in c++

Tags: c++

This is code i used :

```
int cap(long n){
    long sq = n*n;
    string num = to_string(sq),s1,s2;
    cout << num;
    for(int i=1;i<=num.length();i++){
        s1 = num.substr(0,i);
        s2 = num.substr(i,num.length()-i);
        string::size_type sz=0;  
        long n1 = stol (s1,&sz,0);
        long n2 = stol (s2,&sz,0);
        if(n1+n2==n){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[This is the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGUSm.png). Any hint for this type of error?

Comment: Instead of putting snapshot, it is recommended to copy-paste the error message as text.

Answer (score 0):

The loop condition is wrong, you should set

```
for(int i=1;i<num.length();i++){
```

and the program will not crash. Still, I cannot claim if the result is a desired one.

Answer (score 0):

When `i=num.length()`, `s2` is empty as

```
s2 = num.substr(i,num.length()-i);
```

which is same as

```
s2 = num.substr(i, 0);  //for i=num.length()
                   ^~~~~length of substring is zero
```

Then, this **empty string** is passed to `stol` as `s2`, consequently leading to the error "*terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'*"

```
long n2 = stol (s2, &sz, 0);
                 ^~~~~Empty string.
```

[Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OfuG6PbOpe3Wwmo5)